# Create email with multiple recipients from listbox values

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am trying to create an email and populate multiple recipients based off a listbox.

I tried putting the list box column reference in the ".To" line but it gives a null error.

I found code that should loop through the listbox values but it is not populating any recipients.

```vb
Public Sub cmdEmailContact_Click()

    Dim appOutLook As Outlook.Application
    Dim MailOutLook As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFileEnd  As String
    Dim strEmailRecipients As String

    strPath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Invoice Test\GCX"
    strFilter = Me.txtInvNum
    strFileEnd = ".pdf"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & strFilter & strFileEnd)
    strEmailRecipients = ""

    For N = 0 To Me.lstContacts.ListCount - 1
        If Me.lstContacts.Selected(N) = True Then
            strEmailRecipients = strEmailRecipients & "; " & Me.lstContacts.Column(3, N)   
        End If
    Next N

    strEmailRecipients = Mid(strEmailRecipients, 3)

    If strFile <> "" Then

        Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set MailOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With MailOutLook
            .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
            .To = strEmailRecipients
            ''.cc = ""
            ''.bcc = ""
            .Subject = "text here"
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "emailname"
            .HTMLBody = "text here"
            .Attachments.Add (strPath & strFilter & strFileEnd)
            '.Send
            .Display 
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No file matching " & strPath & strFilter & strFileEnd & " found." & vbCrLf & _
                "Process has been stopped."
        Exit Sub   
    End If

End Sub
```

I expect strEmailRecipients to equal a semi-colon separated list of email addresses based off the listbox. There are no error messages.

Comment: I tested your code and it works. The string is built. Are you sure you reference correct column? Column index begins with 0. Have you step debugged? Instead of looping through entire list, loop through ItemsSelected.

Comment: I was referencing the wrong column. It's now returning only the selected email address. So if I have three in the list box it's only returning the one that's selected. I want it to return all of the emails. Since my problem has changed I'll post another question. Thanks

Comment: If you want to return all items in list, don't use `If Me.lstContacts.Selected(N) = True Then`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than building a semi-colon delimited string to populate the [`To`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.to) property of the [`MailItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem) object, you may instead want to modify the contents of the [`Recipients`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients) collection when adding recipients (independent of the recipient type) to a [`MailItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem) object.

Adding an item to the [`Recipients`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients) collection using the [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.add) method will yield a [`Recipient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient) object, which has a [`Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.type) property which may be used to designate the recipient as either to, cc, or bcc by setting the property to [`olTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmailrecipienttype), [`olCC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmailrecipienttype), or [`olBCC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmailrecipienttype) (or `1`, `2`, or `3` if using late binding).

Hence the construction of the email might become something along the lines of the following:

```vb
Dim idx
With MailOutLook
    With .Recipients
        For Each idx In lstContacts.ItemsSelected
            With .Add(lstContacts.ItemData(idx))
                .Type = olTo
            End With
        Next idx
    End With
    .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
    ' ... etc.
End With
```