# Query Outlook Global Address List From Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am writing some Access VBA code to get a count of how many times a specific email address has been emailed.  The issue that I am running into is that the first time the email is sent out, the email leaves our Exchange sever as

```
email1@domain.com
```

But once the person replies to that email, then all subsequent messages are displayed as

```
'lastname, firstname'
```

I use the below VBA code to search for the email1@domain.com example, but how can I use access vba to get the name from the global address list?

```
Function Test()

Dim searchEmail As String: searchEmail = "'abc123@abc123.com'"
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As NameSpace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olReply As Outlook.MailItem
Dim msg As Object
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

For Each msg In Fldr.Items
    If TypeName(msg) = "MailItem" Then
        If msg.To = searchEmail Then
            'now we start counting
        End If
    End If
Next msg

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56843378/7531598), instead of checking the [`To`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.to) property of the [`MailItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem) object (which, per the linked documentation, contains the display names only), query the contents of the [`Recipients`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients) collection and, for each [`Recipient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient) object, test the value held by the [`Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.address) property against your `searchEmail` variable.

The [`Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.address) property will consistently contain the email address of the recipient, never a display name.

That is, instead of:

```
For Each msg In Fldr.Items
    If TypeName(msg) = "MailItem" Then
        If msg.To = searchEmail Then
            'now we start counting
        End If
    End If
Next msg
```

You might use something like:

```
For Each msg In Fldr.Items
    If TypeName(msg) = "MailItem" Then
        For Each rcp In msg.Recipients
            If rcp.Address = searchEmail Then
                'now we start counting
            End If
        Next rcp
    End If
Next msg
```

Comment: So I'm with you 'til here....what goes inside the WIth block? You say to query the contents of the Recipients collection and check each Recipient...how do I do such? Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

With olMail
    With .Recipients
    
    End With
End With

Comment: @HotTomales I have updated my answer to nudge you in the right direction. You may want to consider exiting the innermost `For Each` loop when the email address is found, to avoiding mis-counting emails which contain a recipient more than once.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I was trying to replace my original For Each loop with the For Each loop in your other post. Thanks again!